# How to configure external configuration beans in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I was having trouble with the latest iteration of trying to get a multi-module spring boot application going, and I managed to distill the problem down to a simple test application pasted below (and also available at this gist: https://gist.github.com/deinspanjer/d8416e91c1454bfe44efeee5b00fb805

When I try to run this, it starts up, but then gives the following error.  Please tell me what obvious thing I'm doing wrong. :(

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)

2016-12-10 16:41:04.035  INFO 25026 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : Starting DemoApplication on den with PID 25026 (/Users/dre/src/demo/target/classes started by dre in /Users/dre/src/demo)
2016-12-10 16:41:04.039  INFO 25026 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-12-10 16:41:04.108  INFO 25026 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@21507a04: startup date [Sat Dec 10 16:41:04 EST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-12-10 16:41:04.923  WARN 25026 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'demoApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dc'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'demoConfig' defined in file [/Users/dre/src/demo/target/classes/com/example/config/DemoConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2016-12-10 16:41:04.932  INFO 25026 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2016-12-10 16:41:05.035 ERROR 25026 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.config.DemoConfig required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

application.yml

```
demo:
  foo:
    str_val: Make it work!
    objVal.objVal: This one too!
```

DemoApplication.java

```
package com.example;

import com.example.config.DemoConfig;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    private DemoConfig dc;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        System.out.printf("String val: %s\nObject val: %s", dc.getStrVal(), dc.getObjVal());
    }
}
```

DemoConfig.java

```
package com.example.config;

import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "demo.foo")
public class DemoConfig {
    @NotBlank private final String strVal;
    private final ObjVal objVal;

    @Data
    public static class ObjVal {
        @NotBlank private final String objVal;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Not sure if it's the problem, but the property in application.yml uses an underscore whereas the class attribute uses camel case. Also, can the fields really be final?

Comment: Try removing the `@Component`; I believe you may be getting redundant copies, only one of which gets the environment-injection treatment.

Comment: @Quagaar Spring Boot should handle the first part. Not sure about the second, but I suspect it should work (note that Lombok is inserting a constructor).

Comment: If you remove the component annotation you get a different error that indicates it is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the documentation should help.

Your fields are final, no setters are going to be generated. Yet, [this is a requirement for `@ConfigurationProperties` properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties). Binding does work via standard Java Beans property descriptors. The binder never supported constructor injection.

But that error is different. Dependencies injection is not different from any other component here. You are basically creating a `@Component` that takes a `String` and an `ObjVal` as arguments. So when the application context tries to create the bean, it needs to find two beans matching those types. This has nothing to do with `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Long story short, change your class as follows:

```
package com.example.config;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "demo.foo")
public class DemoConfig {
    @NotBlank private String strVal;
    private final ObjVal objVal = new ObjVal();

   // getter & setter for strVal

   // getter for objVal (we already have an instance so we can "crawl to it")

    public static class ObjVal {
        @NotBlank private String objVal;

        // getter & setter for objVal
  }
}
```

I've removed Lombok to make it explicit that there is no particular constructor now. If you have one, parameters must be spring beans available in the context.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The final modifier was indeed the problem.  I will mention that I certainly did read the documentation several times.  The piece you linked to doesn't explicitly say that you can't use the final keyword.  In fact, it says, "Nested POJO properties can also be created (**so a setter is not mandatory**) if they have a default constructor, or a constructor accepting a single value that can be coerced from String.".  My fault was in not realizing that this only worked for nested POJOs not for the root level POJO.

Comment: I think that documentation bites us back every time I reference it so it's about time we give it some more love. I am sorry you read the doc several times and didn't find a good answer to your question. I've created [#7620](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7620) to address this. Feel free to subscribe to it. Thanks!

Comment: Note that this is no longer true with Spring Boot 2.2 and the `@ConstructorBinding` annotation -- see here: https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/16/spring-boot-2-2-0#immutable-code-configurationproperties-code-binding